# Asset subfolder is not showing in the entry field as a folder option

Tags: assets

I have an asset folder images and I have created a subfolder in the images folder so:

images
   |
subfolder

In my entry fields I am not seeing the subfolder in the asset selection pop-up. Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 3):

Worked this out. In the entry field I was limiting uploading an image to one folder. Once this was unchecked and only images selected in the folder list the subfolder appeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt create the folder in the assets pop-up i.e you just created a new folder manually, then you will need to update your asset indexes in the settings page for it to appear.

You can create subfolders within the pop-up, just right click a directory name and a  `new subfolder` button will appear. The new folder will then display automatically without having to manually re-index